# Setting expire in lpush predis php?

Tags: php, redis, predis

I want to set expiry for redis lpush function:

```
$obj->lpush($key,$id);
$obj->expire($key,EXPIRE_TIME);
```

But I am getting error like:

```
Undefined method expire()
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried `setTimeout`?

Comment: can you share how $obj is defined?